# How to measure power consumption of my application on Android?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, battery, measurement

I have developed an Android application and I would like to know the power consumption of my app on an Android device. I came across various threads on Stack Overflow but none of them helped me.

Is there any application in Android which measures the power consumption of my app or any other viable method?

### Edited

From the answers of [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581333/android-app-power-consumption):

I used "Battery Historian" and generated batteryinfo.txt and batteryinfo.html

The Batteryinfo.txt is as follows

```
Battery History:

      -3m04s883ms 090 6c120104 status=discharging health=overheat plug=none temp=0 volt=3797 +screen +phone_scanning +wifi +wifi_running +wake_lock +sensor brightness=bright phone_state=out

      -3m02s651ms 090 6c1a0104 status=charging plug=usb volt=4123 +plugged

      -3m00s087ms 090 6c1a0104 volt=4090

      -2m57s951ms 090 6c1a0104 volt=4125

      -2m43s775ms 090 6c1a0104 volt=4123

      -2m41s563ms 087 6c1a0104

      -2m31s787ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4114

      -2m28s300ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4112

      -2m26s037ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4114

      -2m22s891ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4112

      -2m20s797ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4134

      -2m08s632ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=3849

      -2m06s567ms 083 6c1a0104 volt=3838

      -2m04s370ms 083 6c1a0104 volt=4123

      -1m43s700ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4122

      -1m32s936ms 087 6c1a0104 volt=4007

      -1m22s724ms 083 6c1a0104 health=good

      -1m02s524ms 080 6c1a0104 volt=3957



Per-PID Stats:

PID 166 wake time: +203ms

PID 109 wake time: +2m57s295ms



Statistics since last charge:

System starts: 0, currently on battery: false

Time on battery: 2s 232ms (0.0%) realtime, 2s 232ms (0.0%) uptime

Total run time: 3d 15h 52m 45s 402ms realtime, 1d 9h 16m 33s 630ms uptime, 

Screen on: 2s 231ms (100.0%), Input events: 0, Active phone call: 0ms (0.0%)

Screen brightnesses: bright 2s 231ms (100.0%)

Kernel Wake lock "PowerManagerService": 2s 191ms  (0 times) realtime

Kernel Wake lock "power-supply": 412ms  (1 times) realtime

Kernel Wake lock "main": 2s 191ms  (0 times) realtime

Total received: 0B, Total sent: 0B

Total full wakelock time: 2s 197ms , Total partial waklock time: 2s 203ms 

Signal levels: none 2s 231ms (100.0%) 0x

Signal scanning time: 2s 231ms 

Radio types: none 2s 231ms (100.0%) 0x

Radio data uptime when unplugged: 0 ms

Wifi on: 2s 231ms (100.0%), Wifi running: 2s 231ms (100.0%), Bluetooth on: 0ms (0.0%)



Device battery use since last full charge

Amount discharged (lower bound): 0

Amount discharged (upper bound): 0

Amount discharged while screen on: 0

Amount discharged while screen off: 0



#1000:

User activity: 2 other

Sensor 2: 2s 206ms realtime (0 times)

#1013:

Wake lock AudioIn_369: 2s 203ms partial (1 times) realtime

#10010:

Apk com.android.providers.media:

  Service com.android.providers.media.MtpService:

    Created for: 0ms  uptime

    Starts: 1, launches: 1

#10029:

Wake lock Samsung Recognition Service: 2s 197ms full (0 times) realtime



Statistics since last unplugged:

Time on battery: 2s 232ms (1.2%) realtime, 2s 232ms (1.2%) uptime

Total run time: 3m 4s 912ms realtime, 3m 4s 911ms uptime, 

Screen on: 2s 232ms (100.0%), Input events: 0, Active phone call: 0ms (0.0%)

Screen brightnesses: bright 2s 232ms (100.0%)

Kernel Wake lock "PowerManagerService": 2s 191ms  (0 times) realtime

Kernel Wake lock "power-supply": 412ms  (1 times) realtime

Kernel Wake lock "main": 2s 191ms  (0 times) realtime

Total received: 0B, Total sent: 0B

Total full wakelock time: 2s 232ms , Total partial waklock time: 2s 232ms 

Signal levels: none 2s 232ms (100.0%) 0x

Signal scanning time: 2s 232ms 

Radio types: none 2s 232ms (100.0%) 0x

Radio data uptime when unplugged: 0 ms

Wifi on: 2s 232ms (100.0%), Wifi running: 2s 232ms (100.0%), Bluetooth on: 0ms (0.0%)



Device is currently plugged into power

  Last discharge cycle start level: 90

  Last discharge cycle end level: 90

  Amount discharged while screen on: 0

  Amount discharged while screen off: 0



 #1000:

   User activity: 2 other

   Sensor 2: 2s 232ms realtime (0 times)

 #1013:

   Wake lock AudioIn_369: 2s 232ms partial (1 times) realtime

 #10010:

   Apk com.android.providers.media:

  Service com.android.providers.media.MtpService:

    Created for: 0ms  uptime

    Starts: 1, launches: 1

 #10029:

    Wake lock Samsung Recognition Service: 2s 232ms full (0 times) realtime
```

When I open Batteryinfo.html it displaying "**Cannot Find End Time**".

I followed the answers in the below post and commented out the code as mentioned

[Battery historian cannot find end time android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487749/battery-historian-cannot-find-end-time-android)

This time when I run the command to generate batteryinfo.html from batteryinfo.html it displaying an error (which is referrinf to the commented out code of 3 lines).

NOTE: As my device is not supporting to use batterystats and so am using batteryinfo.

I want to open the `batteryinfo.html` with the details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581333/android-app-power-consumption

Comment: One way is to look at the Battery within the Phone's settings? Simply drag down from the top, navigate to the Battery feature and then you'll be able to view the power consumption contribution against other applications?

Comment: @Subby, I have 2 applications and I need to know which app is consuming more with a time frame of 15 mins. I just can't report it with some estimated values by checking it in the Settings. I need the exact readings of those 2 apps.

Comment: @John Have you tried out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581333/android-app-power-consumption. The first answer seems promising.

Comment: @Subby, I got to know from other SO Posts that the PowerTutor is bit old and it is not able to compute the exact power consumption http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109301/can-powertutor-app-measure-exact-whole-power-consumption-of-devices-gpu

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by can't read estimated value in the setting.

Look at my answer in [Android App power consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581333/android-app-power-consumption)

"
First, the powertutor from Google Play is out of date. I've checked the source code of it, and find that the power estimation model is for some old mobile model. The value from power tutor is way smaller than the actual power consumption.

Therefore, I would recommend to use Battery Historian which is development by google used to estimate battery consumption of each App. But it's written in Python/Go. It will show the hardware invocation in a html file. And you can find battery consumption of each App in a corresponding text file.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html
"

It will create a batterystats.txt, showing exactly the same as it in the setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Xudong Ran. I tried using "Battery Historian" based on your suggestion and the .txt and .html files are properly generated but when I open the .html file it simply shows that "Cannot Find End Time". Can you help me out over here on how to get rid off this.

Comment: First, if you want to check the power consumption of your application. I suggest you to read batterystat.txt file by finding uid of your application. For the ‘cannot find end time’ problem, I've check the source code. It is exactly the same as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487749/battery-historian-cannot-find-end-time-android If possible, could you paste the txt file here?

Comment: I edited the question with my batteryinfo.txt file. I followed the link you had posted and it too didn't worked out for me. I posted my questions below the answers in that post. Any guidance on the next steps please?

Comment: What's your Android version? I'm afraid for old device there's no API from Android to export a detail power estimation. I've read through batteryinfo.java. It can only provide battery information such as battery level, voltage, and discharge status.

Comment: Android Version - 4.0.4 and API Level 15.

Comment: I'm afraid that Battery Historian only supports Android 4.2+. And I cannot find any power estimation APIs when I'm looking into the source code. I suggest you to use other measuring method. Actually, there are two Apps available on Google Play which can estimate power consumption. One is called "App Tune-up Kit". Another is Trepn Profiler. You can have a try. If have any question, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. I used App Tune-up kit but somehow am facing issues in generating the HTML files. Could you have a look into this for my issue https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/app-tune-kit/33407